# How to use Command on a Label with GestureRecognizers?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make when clicking on a `Label` enter text in an `Entry`. I am doing it with `TapGestureRecognizer` and command but it does nothing, I don't know where the problem can be. The `x:Name` of the `Entry` is `EntryControl`.

My Label:

```
    <Label Margin="10"
           FontSize="30"
           Text="{Binding EmojiSource}">
           <Label.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EmojiTappedCommand}" />
           </Label.GestureRecognizers>
     </Label>
```

Behind Code:

```
           public ICommand EmojiTappedCommand { get; private set; }
    
           public Editor(){
    
                EmojiTappedCommand = new Command(EmojiButtonCommand);
           }
                      
          private void EmojiButtonCommand()
                { 
                    EntryControl.Text ="Tapped";
          
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `BindingContext = this;` in the background code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ICommand EmojiTappedCommand { get; private set; }
        public string EmojiSource { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            EmojiSource = "test";
          
            EmojiTappedCommand = new Command(EmojiButtonCommand);
            BindingContext = this;

          
        }


        private void EmojiButtonCommand()
        {
            EntryControl.Text = "Tapped";

        }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: I have a problem, I can't use BindingContext = this. I'm doing a custom control and using it in a project. In the custom control I bind other properties and I need to add this too, It's imposible without it?

Comment: Does your custom control contains `Label` and `Entry` in Contentview?If not, can you share your custom control's code

Comment: Yes, in the same ContentView.

Comment: If you have binding other perperties. you can add `EmojiTappedCommand ` and `EmojiSource` to your ViewModel. Then add an new property, then `Entry`'s text binding this new property. when `EmojiTappedCommand ` executed, set the value of this new property. Please achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for new property.